# Return 404 (Not Found) when trying to access multiple laravel application dockerized

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

Im trying to dockerize multiple laravel applications on my local machine

My goal is to access these apps using the local domain (ex: app1.localhost, app2.localhost, etc.) that I defined in my docker-compose.yaml

I'm using the nginxproxy/nginx-proxy image and running it independently.

Here is my configuration.

`nginx-proxy > docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

networks:
  default:
    name: local-network
```

The next thing I do is `docker-compose up -d`

After making sure this nginx-proxy runs without error, I moved to my laravel applications.

- App 1

`app1 > docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/nginx.dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8001:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/client
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app1.localhost
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/client:delegated
    ports:
      - '9001:9000'
networks:
  default:
    name: local-network
```

And continue to build the container for my laravel app1.

Im trying to run it with the local domain (app1.localhost), and it runs well without error.

Then I moved to my App 2 with the same configuration above and some adjustments, which is changing the ports and VIRTUAL_HOST

- App 2

`app2 > docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/nginx.dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8002:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/internal
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app2.localhost
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/internal:delegated
    ports:
      - '9002:9000'
networks:
  default:
    name: local-network
```

The build image and container were a success.

Then when I tried to access the local domain (app2.localhost), it returned 404 not found on the screen, and when I checked the container server logs for App 2, it gave the error message below

```
[error] 22#22: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.2, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.3:9000", host: "app2.localhost"
```

Comment: PS: When I stop my app1 containers, try again to access app2.localhost is running well.
Something wrong with my configuration. I can't just figure out which part :(